# A question about the proof of Theorem $3.44$ of Bartle.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Specifically, the part where it proves that $(ii) \implies (iii)$, since I am not clear about what he means by "Continuing in this way, a sub-succession is obtained."

I have read on some internet pages that this refers to induction, however I am not sure what would be the specific property to be demonstrated by induction, that is, what would be the base case and which series would be the inductive step.

Theorem $3.44$

Let $X = (X_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers, Then the following are equivalent:

i) The sequence $X = (X_n)$ does not converge to $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

ii) There exists an $\epsilon_0 >0$ such that for any $ k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_k \geq k$ and $|X_{n_k}-x|\geq \epsilon_o$

iii) There exists an $\epsilon_o >0$ and a subsequence $X´=(X_{n_k})$ of $X$ such that $|X_{n_k}-x|\geq \epsilon_o$ for all $k \in  \mathbb{N}$

Proof.
i) $\Rightarrow $ ii) If $(X_n)$ does not converge to $x$, then for some $\epsilon_0>0$ it is impossible to find natural number $k$ such that for all $n\geq k$ the terms $X_n$ satisfy $|x_n-x|<\epsilon_0$ holds. In other words, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there a exists natural number $n_k \geq k$ such that  $|X_{n_k}-x|\geq \epsilon_o$.

Proof.
ii) $\Rightarrow $ iii) Let $\epsilon_0$ be as in (ii) and let $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $n_1 \geq 1$ and $|X_{n_1}-x|\geq \epsilon_o$.

Now let $n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $n_2>n_1 $ and $|X_{n_2}-x|\geq \epsilon_o$; let $n_3 \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $n_3>n_2 $ and  $|X_{n_3}-x|\geq \epsilon_o$. Continue in this way to obtain a subsequence $X´=(X_{n_k})$ of $X$ such that $|X_{n_k}-x|\geq \epsilon_o$ for all $k \in  \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What was said in proof before "Continuing in this way..."?

Comment: My edit was for a typo, 8th line, $n_k\in \Bbb R$ changed to $n_k\in \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

It is written that

> Let $\epsilon_0$ be as in (ii) and let $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $n_1 \geq 1$ and $|X_{n_1}-x|\geq \epsilon_o$.
>
> Now let $n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $n_2>n_1 $ and $|X_{n_2}-x|\geq \epsilon_0$; let $n_3 \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $n_3>n_2 $ and  $|X_{n_3}-x|\geq \epsilon_0$.

So, "continuing in this way" basically means that you go on choosing $n_k>n_{k-1}$ and $|X_{n_k}-x|\geq \epsilon_0$ and define this to be the the sequence $\{X_{n_k}\}$.

Does that help?